# MPI_Test isn't picking up a completed MPI_Send

Tags: interrupt, openmpi

I've spent three days looking for an answer so I hope you'll bear with me if this has already been addressed and I've been mighty unlucky finding a solution.
I'm using Fortran (eugh!) but this is a generic MPI query.

Scenario (simplified for this example):

- Processes 0 and 1 communicate with process 2 (but not with each other)
- 0 & 1 do lots of sends/receives
- 2 does lots of receives/process/sends (but each pair is done twice so as to
  pick up both 0 & 1)
- 0 & 1 will eventually stop - I know not when! - so I do an MPI_Send from each when appropriate using the rank of the 3rd process (filter_rank_id=2) and a special tag (c_tag_open_rcv=200), with a logical TRUE in the buffer (end_of_run). Like this:

`CALL MPI_SEND(end_of_run, 1, MPI_LOGICAL, filter_rank_id, c_tag_open_rcv, mpi_coupling_comms, mpi_err)`

The problem arises in process 2... it's busy doing its MPI_Recv/MPI_Send pairs and I cannot break out of it. I have set up a non-blocking receive for each of the other two processes and stored the request handles:

```
    DO model_rank_id= 0, 1
        !Set up a non-blocking receive to get notification of end of model run for each model
        end_run = end_model_runs(model_rank_id) !this is an array of booleans initialised to FALSE
        CALL MPI_IRECV(end_run, 1, MPI_LOGICAL, model_rank_id, &
                       c_tag_open_rcv, coupling_comms, mpi_request_handle, mpi_err)
        !store the handle in an array
        request_handles(model_rank_id) = mpi_request_handle                
    END DO
```

where model_rank_id is the process number in the MPI communicator i.e. 0 or 1.

Later on, busy doing all those receive/send pairs, I always check whether anything's arrived in the buffer:

```
    DO model_rank_id= 0, 1
        IF (end_model_runs(model_rank_id) .EQV. .FALSE.) THEN
            CALL MPI_TEST(request_handles(model_rank_id), run_complete, mpi_status, mpi_err)
            IF (run_complete .eqv. .FALSE.) THEN
                !do stuff... receive/process/send
            ELSE
                !run is complete
                !___________removed this as I realised it was incorrect__________
                !get the stop flag for the specific process
                CALL MPI_RECV(end_run, 1, MPI_LOGICAL, model_rank_id, &
                                    c_tag_open_rcv, coupling_comms, mpi_err)
                !____________end_________________________________________________
                !store the stop flag so I can do a logical 'AND' on it and break out when
                !both processes have sent their message
                end_model_runs(model_rank_id) = end_run
            END IF
        END IF
    END DO
```

Note that this snippet is contained in a loop which carries on until all the stop flags are TRUE.

I know it's fairly complex, but this can't be that hard, can it? If anyone can see the error that'd be fantastic, or even suggest a better way to do it.

Huge thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is probably stuck in the `MPI_RECV` call. The reason is that having a positive completion flag as returned by `MPI_TEST` means that `MPI_IRECV` has **received the message**. Unless the sender sends another message with the same tag, `MPI_RECV` will simply block and wait, in your case probably indefinitely. Apart from that, you are issuing two `MPI_IRECV` calls with the same receive buffer which is probably not what you really want to do since `end_run = end_model_runs(model_rank_id)` does not copy the address of the array element into `end_run` but rather its value.

Your code should look like this:

```
DO model_rank_id= 0, 1
    !Set up a non-blocking receive to get notification of end of model run for each model
    CALL MPI_IRECV(end_model_runs(model_rank_id), 1, MPI_LOGICAL, model_rank_id, &
                   c_tag_open_rcv, coupling_comms, request_handle, ierr)
    !store the handle in an array
    request_handles(model_rank_id) = request_handle                
END DO

...

DO model_rank_id= 0, 1
    IF (end_model_runs(model_rank_id) .EQV. .FALSE.) THEN
        CALL MPI_TEST(request_handles(model_rank_id), run_complete, status, ierr)
        IF (run_complete .eqv. .FALSE.) THEN
            !do stuff... receive/process/send
        ELSE
            !run is complete
            !the stop flag is ALREADY in end_model_runs(model_rank_id)
            !do a logical 'AND' on it and break out when
        END IF
    END IF
END DO
```

As a side note, using your own identifiers that start with `mpi_` is a terrible idea since those might clash with symbols provided by the MPI library. You should really treat `mpi_` as a reserved prefix and never use it while naming your own variables, subroutines, etc. I've fixed that for you in the code above.

Comment: I've removed that redundant `MPI_RECV` call (see edit) as I realised it wasn't matched with another send. However, the code never got into that in the first place! My print output show that `MPI_TEST` is always returning False, even when I can see that the other processes have sent to the correct destination.
re use of `mpi_` is that a Fortran thing... not being case sensitive?

Comment: Mind that such short messages consisting of a single logical value are most likely buffered at the sender or sent eagerly. The reason for the failing test is probably somewhere in the code not shown. As for the prefix, no, it's not a Fortran thing. Using `MPI_` in C/C++ is also a bad practice.

Comment: I found it eventually - it's a timing problem - if I stick a `sleep` in, the test picks up the completed send. Thanks for your help anyway :)

re use of `mpi_`: I was changing the case to distinguish it from `MPI_` where in C/C++ these would be treated differently.

Comment: `MPI_TEST` is intended to be called continuously in a loop - a single call won't do much in many cases. If you simply want to wait until there is a message from any of the processes, issue an `MPI_RECV` with a source rank of `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`. If you want to periodically check for message availability, use `MPI_IPROBE`, again with `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`. The latter requires a consecutive `MPI_RECV` in order to receive the message.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this eventually after a lot of experimentation, it was actually quite simple (isn't it always?)

The problem was due to the fact that processes 0 & 1 could end and post their "I'm finished" messages OK, but process 2 was in such a tight loop doing the test and recv/send pair (the outer loops on both sets of send/recv's omitted for clarity in original past), that the test would fail and the process would stick in the blocking `MPI_RECV`.

First I tried a sleep(3) which made it work, but it couldn't sleep on every loop without really bad effects on perfomance, then I tried an `MPI_IPROBE` but hit the same problem as the test. In the end, a timeout around the `MPI_IPROBE` did the trick, thus:

```
        DO iter1 = 1, num_models

            !Test each model in turn and ensure we do the comms until it has finished
            IF (end_model_runs(iter1) .EQV. .FALSE.) THEN                        
                model_rank_id= models(iter1)
                now = TIME()
                DO WHILE (TIME() .LT. now + timeout)
                    msg_flag = .FALSE.
                    CALL MPI_IPROBE(model_rank_id, c_tag, coupling_comms, &
                                msg_flag, empi_status, empi_err)
                    IF (msg_flag .EQV. .TRUE.) THEN
                        !Message waiting
                        EXIT
                    END IF
                END DO

                IF (msg_flag .EQV. .TRUE.) THEN
                    CALL MPI_RECV(state_vector, num_state_params, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                                  model_rank_id, c_tag, coupling_comms, empi_status, empi_err)
                ELSE !no message waiting, flag should be False, i.e. the run *has* finished
                    end_model_runs(iter1) = .NOT. msg_flag
                END IF
            END IF
        END DO
```

and this code inside a loop which breaks once all the members of `end_model_runs` are `TRUE`.

I hope this helps someone else - and saves them three days of effort!